# Values are set randomly and not as specified by the code

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to specify a variable based on the value of another variable.
However, the line of coding shown below, it is not working correctly.
The values of "price-sensitivity" are set randomly, and not as specified by the code.

I don't know where I have gone wrong. Please help!

```
    breed[households household]

links-own [strength
]

households-own [income
  price-sensitivity
]

to setup
clear-all
create-households 1000
create-income
create-sensitivity
end


to create-income ; Three main categories <20'000, 20'000 - 40'000, >40'000
 ask n-of (0.3 * 1000) households [set income 1001 + random 19000]
 ask n-of (0.5 * 1000) households [set income 20001 + random 20000]
 ask n-of (0.2 * 1000) households [set income 40001 + random 60000]
  ask households [if any? households with [income = 0] [set income 1001 + random 90000]]
end

to create-sensitivity ; Low Sensitivity=-10 High Sensitivity=10
 ask households [if income <= 20000 [set price-sensitivity (1 + random 10)]
 if income > 20000 or income <= 40000 [set price-sensitivity (-8 + random 10)]
 if income > 40000 [set price-sensitivity (3 + random -13)]]
 ask households [if price-sensitivity = 0 [set price-sensitivity (-1 + random -9)]]
end
```

Comment: I don't know NetLogo, but I think maybe `if income > 20000 or income <= 40000` is wrong, as it should be an `and` condition instead. You could have debugged this by setting a fixed value under each condition, so you know exactly which condition is being executed and then find what's wrong.

Comment: Using and doesn't fix the problem. I have tried. Thanks though

Comment: Did you try setting fixed values instead of random to understand what's going on?

Comment: There is a logic error. As said  by Andrew, `if income > 20000 or income <= 40000` is wrong. This should be AND. As in, "if the income is greater than 20K AND the income is less than 40K"  You are trying to select income brackets. With OR, EVERY INCOME passes that test.  0 is < 40000, 100000 is > 20000.

Comment: You may be making incorrect assumptions about how `N-OF` works. It chooses items at random, so in your three lines, the same agent may be picked more than once. If you want to guarantee those divisions, you will need to use a different method.

Comment: OH:::   You are asking each households to see if ANY households have income 0, and if so set the income of this household  So, if there is even one income of 0, ALL the households change income.  Is that what you meant? Maybe you meant `ask households with [ income = 0 ] [ set income.... ]`

Comment: Finally, what do you mean by "randomly?" You are definitely setting things to random values....?  Maybe you meant, "incorrectly?"  As Andrew suggested, temporarily using different values for each income, etc, instead of random, may help you see which part of the code is doing what.